# jquery ajax nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have nested callabcks but resulted output is not ordered correctly. My ajax results are in ascending orders of id but html generated is random. can someone help me out pls?

```
var formatedhtml = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/read',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            console.log(value);
            getdetails(value['id'], function(output) {
                formatedhtml = formatedhtml +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-6">' +
                    ' <div class="row">' +
                    ' <div class="orderno">' + value['id'] + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="tableno">' + value['tableno'] + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="ordertype">' + value['type'] + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="timestamp">' + value['created'] + '</div>' +
                    ' </div>' +
                    '<hr>';
                $.each(JSON.parse(output['items']), function(k, val) {
                    formatedhtml = formatedhtml + '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="quantity">' + val[3] + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="item">' + '</div>' +
                        '</div>';

                });
                formatedhtml = formatedhtml +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="notes">' + value['id'] + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $("#orderlist").html(formatedhtml);
                console.log(output);
            });

        });

    }
});
```

edit:

Here is `getdetails` function. its an ajax request.

```
function getdetails(id, callback) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/readdetails',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: is getDetails() a $.ajax request?

Comment: yes it is ajax request

Comment: Use array of promises that each `$.ajax` returns. Then use `$.when` to run your html processing code when all the promises have been resolved. The arguments in `$.when` callback will be in same order as requests were started in the loop regardless of order they were completed

Comment: charlietfl thanx for reply let me try it. can you add answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this, one is to use a promise and sort by id when all requests are done. Another you could create the template and append the details on callback as each detail request has an id you can define in your template a class like 'id-'+value['id'] and use jquery selector and append detail template.

Another solution would be to create a function loop that calls itself untill orderCount == orderLoaded.

Job is done synchronously (takes more time)

```js
//Mock ajax function
$.ajax = function (param) {
    if(param.url.indexOf('readdetails') != -1){
    param.success(itemsData);
    } else {
      param.success(ordersData);
   }
};

//Mock data
var ordersData = [
  { id : 1, tableno : 'xyz', type: 'invoice', created: '01/01/2001' },
  { id : 2, tableno : 'xyz', type: 'invoice', created: '01/01/2001' },
  { id : 3, tableno : 'xyz', type: 'invoice', created: '01/01/2001' }
];

var itemsData = [
  { id : 1, orderid: 1, quantity: 5  },
  { id : 2, orderid: 1, quantity: 2  },
  { id : 3, orderid: 1, quantity: 1  }
];

// Globals
var formatedhtml = [];
var orders = [];
var lastOrderLoaded = 0;
var BASE_URL = 'localhost/';

function tpl(order, items) {
    var html = '<tr class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-6">' +
        
        ' <td class="orderno">' + order['id'] + '</td>' +
        '<td class="tableno">' + order['tableno'] + '</td>' +
        '<td class="ordertype">' + order['type'] + '</td>' +
        '<td class="timestamp">' + order['created'] + '</td>' +
        ' </tr>';

    $.each(items, function(key, item) {
      html += '<tr class="row">' +
        '<td class="item">item: ' + item.id + '</td>' +
        '<td class="quantity">quantity: ' + item.quantity + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    });

    html +=
      '<tr class="row">' +
      '<td class="notes"> notes </td>' +
      '<td class="notes"> order id ' + order['id'] + '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</tr>';

    formatedhtml.push({ id: order.id, html : html });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/read',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        lastOrderLoaded = 0;
        orders = data;
        getdetails(orders[0]);
      }
    
});


function getdetails(order) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/readdetails',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: order.id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
           tpl(order, data);
          
           if(lastOrderLoaded < orders.length - 1){
              lastOrderLoaded++;
              getdetails(orders[lastOrderLoaded]);
          } else {
            formatedhtml.forEach(function(element){
               $("#orderlist").append(element.html);
             }); // end each
          }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="orderlist" border="1">
  <tr><th>id</th><th>no</th><th>type</th><th>date</th></tr>
</table>
```

Promise Solution:
Job is done asynchronously (might take less time also bombards the server with many requests at once)

```
var formatedhtml = [];

function tpl(order, items) {
    var html = '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-6">' +
        ' <div class="row">' +
        ' <div class="orderno">' + order['id'] + '</div>' +
        '<div class="tableno">' + order['tableno'] + '</div>' +
        '<div class="ordertype">' + order['type'] + '</div>' +
        '<div class="timestamp">' + order['created'] + '</div>' +
        ' </div>' +
        '<hr>';

    $.each(JSON.parse(items['items']), function(key, item) {
      var html += '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="quantity">' + item[3] + '</div>' +
        '<div class="item">' + '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    });

    html +=
      '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="notes">' + order['id'] + '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    formatedhtml.push({ id: order.id, html : html });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/read',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        var syncLoad = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            syncLoad.push(getdetails(value, tpl));            
        });

        $.when.apply($, syncLoad).done(function() {

          formatedhtml.sort(function(a, b){
                        return a.id - b.id;
          });

          formatedhtml.forEach(function(element){
            $("#orderlist").append(element.html);
          });

      });
    }
});


function getdetails(order, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/readdetails',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: order.id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            callback(order, data[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can u explain your first answer a bit pls? i cant get it working. i think you have mixed ajax calls in first reply. second is working but tis not what i was looking for

Comment: Synchronously: call getdetails > on success build html then call getdetails again until you finish all orders details. This ensures that you keep the fetch order. In your code you call getdetails multiple times almost at once and success does not trigger in the same order you made the requests therefore the order you see html is messed up. Best way is to create a promise (wait for all requests to finish, then sort, then build html and append).

Comment: I edited the answer and added a running example for classic function loop.

Answer (score -2):

Use async:false in your getDetails() ajax call.

```
function getdetails(id, callback) {
var result;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/orders/readdetails',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {
        id: id,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data[0]);


    }
});
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution and it is deprecated by the browsers and should never ever be used. It blocks the whole UI and now you are going to loop through a bunch of them which can lead to lots of problems...don't do it! Will also see the deprecation warnings in browser console

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Comment: Yes I know calling ajax within loop is terrible solution. To avoid this try to get details from single ajax call with json result and do iteration to do display as you want. So you should result necessary data from server side in json fomat.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with loop. A series of async requests will go simultaneously, using synchronous requests each will not be able to go until the prior one completes and in the meantime nothing else will work in the whole page. Will take much longer and if any of them fail or take a long time can cause a lot of issues

Comment: Nobody has been doing this for years for this very reason and there is no need ever to do it...promises make it very easy to work around

Comment: 4 year old chrome notice https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs

Comment: 5 year old msdn article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wer/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously/